# Add score +30 if doc[‘someField’].value == “some”

Tags: elasticsearch

I have document:

```
{
  "_id": 111,
  "price": 1000,
  "color": "red",
}
```

I'm use function_score with gauss function for get score by price.
Now, i need add +30 score if color == "green". Preferably without use groovy script.
But, if color != "green", then still get this document in result, just without these extra 30 points score.
There are ideas in which direction to look?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Constant Score` to give a fixed score to documents that matches that query and put it under a `should` clause so it's not mandatory.

For example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "function_score": {
            "functions": [
              {
                "gauss": {
                  "price": {
                    "origin": "100",
                    "scale": "10"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "match": {
                "color": {
                  "value": "red"
                }
              }
            },
            "boost": 30
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```